# Como colocar um cursor de texto para iniciar na direita? Calculadora

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Estou fazendo uma calculadora básica e na tela de calculo, quero que os números sejam "impressos" da direita para a esquerda. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: `text-align: right;` não resolve?

Comment: Não acredito que perdi tempo me batendo com isso. Tentei de outras formas e nada. É isso mesmo, RESOLVIDO, obrigado!

Comment: @bfavaretto podes juntar isso como resposta...

Comment: @bfavaretto Esse é um cara que não veio ao mundo por votos! Que benevolência! =D

Comment: Pronto, os votos vão pro Jedaias. Boa ação do dia :)

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
text-align: right;
```

e pronto! rsrsrsrsr...

Resposta dada no comentário por @bfavaretto

Comment: rsrsrsrsrsrs...

Comment: Eu não acho justo votarem contra esta resposta por eu já ter comentado a mesma coisa antes. Eu intencionalmente abri mão de postar uma resposta, então quem votou contra por esse motivo, considere reverter o voto.